# How to generate specific version of nuget package from azure pipelines using yaml configuration

Tags: azure-devops, nuget-package, azure-pipelines

I have a build configuration defined here:

https://github.com/cpoDesign/APIFramework/blob/master/azure-pipelines.yml

I have managed to generate a nuget package using the following command

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: pack
    projects: '**/*ApiFramework.csproj'
```

A subset of the task output of the script is

```
  Task "PackTask"
2018-11-27T23:02:32.4459067Z          Successfully created package '/home/vsts/work/1/a/CPODesign.ApiFramework.1.0.0.nupkg'.
```

Next step resolved:

I do not want to create a build with release into nuget as those steps have to be logically separated. Therefore I have created a new step Create a drop.

**Configuration:**

My drop task definition:

```
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    pathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    artifactName: drop
    contents: '**/$(BuildConfiguration)/**/?(*.nupkg)'
```

**Build output:**

```
2018-11-27T23:04:24.6351310Z ##[section]Starting: PublishBuildArtifacts
2018-11-27T23:04:24.6353582Z ==============================================================================
2018-11-27T23:04:24.6353896Z Task         : Publish Build Artifacts
2018-11-27T23:04:24.6353944Z Description  : Publish build artifacts to Azure Pipelines/TFS or a file share
2018-11-27T23:04:24.6354007Z Version      : 1.142.2
2018-11-27T23:04:24.6354046Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2018-11-27T23:04:24.6354091Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=708390)
2018-11-27T23:04:24.6354156Z ==============================================================================
2018-11-27T23:04:26.1357631Z ##[section]Async Command Start: Upload Artifact
2018-11-27T23:04:26.1357755Z Uploading 1 files
2018-11-27T23:04:26.6373194Z File upload succeed.
2018-11-27T23:04:26.6373313Z Upload '/home/vsts/work/1/a' to file container: '#/1558454/drop'
2018-11-27T23:04:27.9231805Z Associated artifact 91 with build 806
2018-11-27T23:04:27.9231947Z ##[section]Async Command End: Upload Artifact
2018-11-27T23:04:27.9232436Z ##[section]Finishing: PublishBuildArtifacts
```

**Note:** The UI for azure-devops has changed and the artefacts (artifacts) are no longer created as a new tab but rather badly added into the report summary

**The question:**

How do I generate a specific version of nuget package IE: 1.0.%(Build.BuildId)?

My last attempt is

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: pack
    projects: '**/*ApiFramework.csproj'
   # packageVersion:'1.0.$(Build.BuildId)'
```

where

> ```
>    packageVersion:'1.0.$(Build.BuildId)'
> ```

Will cause the build to fail
(the current branch is published here:https://github.com/cpoDesign/APIFramework/blob/cpoDesign-build-mods-1/azure-pipelines.yml)

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're question could be a case for looking into _GitVersion_. Using the GitVersion task from you build you'll be able to version your assemblies and packages in a semi-automated fashion. Have a look at their [docs](https://gitversion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [repo](https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after frustrating couple hours I have found the answer

1. Publish the generated nuget package into build artefacts
2. Generate a release to publish the nuget package

---

### Build configuration

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'Ubuntu 16.04'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- script: dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: restore
    projects: '**/*.csproj'

- script: dotnet test **/*.Tests.Unit.csproj --logger trx
- task: PublishTestResults@2
  inputs:
    testRunner: VSTest
    testResultsFiles: '**/*.trx'

- script: dotnet pack /p:PackageVersion='1.0.$(Build.BuildId)' --configuration $(buildConfiguration)  -o $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    pathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    artifactName: drop
    contents: '**/$(BuildConfiguration)/**/?(*.nupkg)'
```

### Release section

I have updated the release to trigger after each successful build

```
dotnet nuget push artefactName.APIFramework/drop/CPODesign.ApiFramework.1.0.$(Build.BuildId).nupkg -k $(myapiKey) -s https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

Comment: Very helpful, Thx. 'script: dotnet pack' that's what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the contents as a valid input in the YAML for PublishBuildArtifacts@1

Do you mean to do a copy task first before you do the publish task. Like shown in the publish documentation?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=vsts